# Hide blueimp indicator when using mobile device?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, blueimp

For my website gallery i'm using Twitter Bootstrap und the blueimp gallery. It's working fine, but i needed to change the size of the indicator, cause i don't wanted such small circles like in the standard version of the blueimp gallery.

Thats what it normally look like:

[image: Standard Version]

And thats my version:

[image: My Version]

So you see, the indicator is bigger on my version. I like that, cause you have a better look on all pictures in my gallery.

But now the problem:

Whey i open the my gallery on a mobile device, the indicator is to big.. Take a look on this example:

[image: Mobile Device]

Now i tried to change it via Media Query like this:

```
@media(max-width:768px) {
    .blueimp-gallery>.indicator>li {
        width: 10px !important;
        height: 10px !important;
    }
}
@media(max-width:992px) {
    .blueimp-gallery>.indicator>li {
        width: 10px !important;
        height: 10px !important;
    }
}
```

or this:

```
@media(max-width:768px) {
    .blueimp-gallery>.indicator>li {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
@media(max-width:992px) {
    .blueimp-gallery>.indicator>li {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

But it didn't work.. Still the same size and no hiding.

Could you help me?

**EDIT:**

The HTML of the gallery:

```
                    <!-- The Bootstrap Image Gallery lightbox, should be a child element of the document body -->
                <div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls" data-use-bootstrap-modal="false">
                    <!-- The container for the modal slides -->
                    <div class="slides"></div>
                    <!-- Controls for the borderless lightbox -->
                    <h3 class="title"></h3>
                    <a class="prev">‹</a>
                    <a class="next">›</a>
                    <a class="close">×</a>
                    <a class="play-pause"></a>
                    <ol class="indicator"></ol>
                    <!-- The modal dialog, which will be used to wrap the lightbox content -->
                    <div class="modal fade">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body next"></div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left prev">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i>
                                        Previous
                                    </button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next">
                                        Next
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div id="event" class="col-md-12">
                <h3 class="page-header heading-primary-a">Events & Bands</h3>
                    <a href="img/gallery/event_01.jpg" title="Events & Bands" data-gallery="#blueimp-gallery-event">
                        <img src="img/gallery/event_thumb.jpg" class="device" alt="Events & Bands">
                    </a>
                    <a href="img/gallery/event_02.jpg" title="Events & Bands" data-gallery="#blueimp-gallery-event">
                        <img src="img/gallery/event_02.jpg" alt="Events & Bands" class="hidden">
                    </a>
                    <a href="img/gallery/event_03.jpg" title="Events & Bands" data-gallery="#blueimp-gallery-event">
                        <img src="img/gallery/event_03.jpg" alt="Events & Bands" class="hidden">
                    </a>
                    <a href="img/gallery/event_04.jpg" title="Events & Bands" data-gallery="#blueimp-gallery-event">
                        <img src="img/gallery/event_04.jpg" alt="Events & Bands" class="hidden">
                    </a>
                    <a href="img/gallery/event_05.jpg" title="Events & Bands" data-gallery="#blueimp-gallery-event">
                        <img src="img/gallery/event_05.jpg" alt="Events & Bands" class="hidden">
                    </a>
                    <a href="img/gallery/event_06.jpg" title="Events & Bands" data-gallery="#blueimp-gallery-event">
                        <img src="img/gallery/event_06.jpg" alt="Events & Bands" class="hidden">
                    </a>
                    <a href="img/gallery/event_07.jpg" title="Events & Bands" data-gallery="#blueimp-gallery-event">
                        <img src="img/gallery/event_07.jpg" alt="Events & Bands" class="hidden">
                    </a>
                    <a href="img/gallery/event_08.jpg" title="Events & Bands" data-gallery="#blueimp-gallery-event">
                        <img src="img/gallery/event_08.jpg" alt="Events & Bands" class="hidden">
                    </a>
                    <a href="img/gallery/event_09.jpg" title="Events & Bands" data-gallery="#blueimp-gallery-event">
                        <img src="img/gallery/event_09.jpg" alt="Events & Bands" class="hidden">
                    </a>
                    <a href="img/gallery/event_10.jpg" title="Events & Bands" data-gallery="#blueimp-gallery-event">
                        <img src="img/gallery/event_10.jpg" alt="Events & Bands" class="hidden">
                    </a>
                </div>
           </div>
```

Comment: Post your HTML as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that HTML, You are targeting with wrong CSS selectors. Try with the below

```
@media (max-width:992px) {
  #events .page-header img {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
  }
}
```

Please avoid the usage of `!important` and use the above CSS after all the CSS is loaded.